# How do I pass an Extension type from cython to an imported C library

Tags: cython, lirc

I'm creating a cython wrapper around the lirc library. I've had to wrap up the lirc_config struct as described by [the tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#writing-a-wrapper-class) but I need to pass a `struct lirc_config *` to a function in the library.

So, the struct in question is (from /usr/include/lirc/lirc_client.h):

```
struct lirc_config {
    char *current_mode;
    struct lirc_config_entry *next;
    struct lirc_config_entry *first;

    int sockfd;
};
```

and the function I need to call is:

```
int lirc_code2char(struct lirc_config *config, char *code, char **string);
```

Here is my cython wrapper around `struct lirc_config`:

```
cdef class LircConfig:

    cdef lirc_client.lirc_config * _c_lirc_config

    def __cinit__(self, config_file):
        lirc_client.lirc_readconfig(config_file, &self._c_lirc_config, NULL)
        if self._c_lirc_config is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._c_lirc_config is not NULL:
            lirc_client.lirc_freeconfig(self._c_lirc_config)
```

and the problematic line:

```
config = LircConfig(configname)
lirc_client.lirc_code2char(config, code, &character)
```

`config` needs to be a pointer to the struct. This:

```
lirc_client.lirc_code2char(&config, code, &character)
```

gives me the error:

```
cylirc.pyx:76:39: Cannot take address of Python variable
```

which makes sense because the `&` is trying to access the address of LircConfig.

This:

```
lirc_client.lirc_code2char(config._c_lirc_config, code, &character)
```

gives me the error:

```
cylirc.pyx:76:45: Cannot convert Python object to 'lirc_config *'
```

Hm, I thought I defined `config._c_lirc_config` as `cdef lirc_client.lirc_config *`. I can't seem to access the value of the `struct lirc_config *`.

I've tried casting and also adding the public tag to _c_lirc_config (as mentioned at the bottom of the [Extension types document](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html)).

I have no idea how to call the `lirc_code2char` function, because cython won't let me access the struct lirc_config pointer. Any Cython experts out there?

Comment: I fixed it by moving the lirc_code2char function inside the LircConfig class, but now it segfaults. :/

Comment: From what you gave, I don't really see why `lirc_client.lirc_code2char(<lirc_client.lirc_config*>config._c_lirc_config, code, &character)` wouldn't work. Could you post the entire `.pyx`, if it is not too long ? And possibly a full use case ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to compile the following without any problem :

```
#lirc_client.pyx

cdef extern from "lirc/lirc_client.h":
    struct lirc_config:
        pass

    int lirc_readconfig(char *file, lirc_config **config, char *s)
    void lirc_freeconfig(lirc_config *config)

    int lirc_nextcode(char **code)
    int lirc_code2char(lirc_config *config, char *code, char **string)

cdef class LircConfig:

    cdef lirc_config * _c_lirc_config

    def __cinit__(self, config_file):
        lirc_readconfig(config_file, &self._c_lirc_config, NULL)
        if self._c_lirc_config is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._c_lirc_config is not NULL:
            lirc_freeconfig(self._c_lirc_config)

    def some_code2char(self, configname):
        cdef char * character
        cdef char * code
        if (lirc_nextcode(&code) == O):
            config = LircConfig(configname)
            lirc_code2char(config._c_lirc_config, code, &character)
```

This works too :

```
def some_code2char(self):
    cdef char * character
    cdef char * code
    if (lirc_nextcode(&code) == O):
        #config = LircConfig(configname)
        lirc_code2char(self._c_lirc_config, code, &character)
```

Note : No use of a `.pyd`

If this segfaults, it is more a matter of usage of the original library, than a Cython issue, I think...

Hope this helps, if not keep me in touch...